# ls pattern matching

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards, patterns

I know that `[]` is working in `ls` pattern matching:

```
$ ls
foo.c  foo.h
$ ls foo.[ch]
foo.c  foo.h
```

but I cannot find where this is documented.

I would like to know the syntax that would match these:

```
$ ls
foo.asd  foo.qwe
```

This is the best guess I had: `ls foo.[{asd}{qwe}]`. It did not work.

Comment: It is not "pattern matching" from `ls` but "shell globbing"; see the shell documentation for all the details. `ls` gets just to see what the shell expands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for the brace expansion `{asd,qwe}`:

```
$ ls foo.{asd,qwe}
foo.asd  foo.qwe
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. @Janis comment helped me find documentation, eg here: http://linux.die.net/Linux-CLI/x11655.htm

Comment: Note that this is not pattern matching, but brace expansion; even if it works for this specific case you cannot match arbitrary patterns with it.

Comment: @Janis: I think OP is looking for this actually, the examples on the question also suggests so..probably he/she could not clarified query enough..see OP's comment above..

Comment: @heemayl; as said, it seems to suffice for his needs. But in his question he clearly spoke about "pattern matching" and "the syntax that would match".

Comment: According to this: linux.die.net/Linux-CLI/x11655.htm , this brace expansion qualifies as standard wildcards or globbing pattern. I am not sure how "pattern matching" differs from "globbing pattern". Strangely, `man 7 glob` describes `[]` but not `{}`.

Comment: @Gauthier: globbing is synonymous to pattern matching in shell, i think what Janis meant is to use extented pattern matching using extended glob..

Comment: @heemayl; yes, this was the semantics. @Gauhier; no, brace expansion is not equivalent to or from the cathegory "pattern matching". Brance expansion is just a textual expansion and will produce an error if used in a globbing context and one of the generated file names is not existing. Observe the difference of `ls *.{foo,bar,baz}` and `*.@(foo|bar|baz)` in case there's no `*.baz` file. Similarly the globbing pattern `*.[ch]` is not equivalent to the brace expansion `*.{c,h}`. - That is the main reason why I would not (or only in very specific cases) suggest to use brace expansion for globbing.

Answer (score 2):

The globbing pattern would be `ls foo.@(asd|qwe)`. This works

- out of the box in ksh;
- in bash also if "extended globbing" is activated with `shopt -s extglob`;
- in zsh if ksh-style globs are activated with `setopt ksh_glob`.

Comment: link to [Bash Extended Globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing)